# Python Panel Template change the Title from Bokeh Application to MyApp

Tags: python, jinja2, panel-pyviz

I am running the example https://panel.pyviz.org/user_guide/Templates.html and would like to change the title from "Bokeh Application" to "My App".

```
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

pn.extension()
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
jinja_template = env.get_template('z_base.html')

tmpl = pn.Template(jinja_template)

tmpl.add_panel('A', hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]))
tmpl.add_panel('B', hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]))

tmpl.show();
```

with html z_base.html extending base:

```
{% extends base %}

<title>{% block title %}My App{% endblock %}</title> <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK !!!! -->

{% block postamble %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
{% endblock postamble %}


{% block contents %}

<h1>Custom Template App 3</h1>
<p>This is a Panel app with a custom template allowing us to compose multiple Panel objects into a single HTML document.</p>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
     {{ embed(roots.A) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      {{ embed(roots.B) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

base template refer to the 
`title <title>{% block title %}{{ title | e if title else "Panel App" }}{% endblock %}</title>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% block head %}
<head>
    {% block inner_head %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{{ title | e if title else "Panel App" }}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block preamble %}{% endblock %}
    {% block resources %}
        {% block css_resources %}
        {{ bokeh_css | indent(8) if bokeh_css }}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block js_resources %}
        {{ bokeh_js | indent(8) if bokeh_js }}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block postamble %}{% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

How can I pass the title variable to the base template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EMayorga answer didn't work, but I think what is intended is to extend and *implement* that block. I got it to work from doing this in my template:

```
{% extends base %}

{% block title %}
{{ html_title }}
{% endblock %}

<!-- goes in body -->
{% block postamble %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcd ... 
...
```

And then in python: `tmpl.add_variable('html_title', 'Demo 23')`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need and couldn't find an answer anywhere on the documentation. Your question here helped guide me, so I wanted to report the simple solution I've found.

I ended up going through the `panel.template` [module code](https://panel.holoviz.org/_modules/panel/template.html) and [API doc](https://panel.holoviz.org/api/panel.template.html) to look for hints. It turns out you can pass your custom title to the `servable` or `show` methods. In your code, it would look like this:

```py
tmpl.show(title="My App");
```

I've tested it with both `servable` and `show` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! I forgot about this post and came across it just now.